# Find mean of difference between dates -Sql Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table with below details

```
Repid | buildDate          | BuildVersion
---------------------------------
 1     2013-11-15 10:41:00  1683
 1     2013-11-15 11:10:00  1684
 1     2013-11-15 12:14:00  1685
 2     2013-11-15 10:41:00  1688
 2     2013-11-15 11:10:00  1689
 2     2013-11-15 12:14:00  1690
```

for each Repid, i need to find the average of difference in hours between successive build versions.

Comment: Can you paste the desired out put here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  b1.RepId
,       avg(abs(datediff(hour, b1.buildDate, b2.buildDate)))
from    builds b1
join    builds b2
on      b1.BuildVersion = b2.BuildVersion + 1
        and b1.Repid = b2.Repid
group by
        b1.RepId
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2797/1/0)

Comment: It gives difference in minus(-), so you should change it to b2.buildDate - b1.buildDate

Comment: add abs before call datediff-

Comment: That works! just that the date parameters need to be swapped in my case datediff(hour, b2.buildDate, b1.buildDate).

Comment: @Velthune : If it work by swapping parameters then why you want to add extra abs() function ?

Comment: mmmmm!!! ignorant!!! if take a look at this example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb09d/1), you obtain a minus value (without abs)

Comment: @Velthune : yes, but OP said that it works by swapping parameters and also I told it in my first comment, so why need to add extra abs() function